# How to refill C:\Windows\twain_32 folder?

Tags: windows, drivers, dynamic-web-twain

I have one computer who has only wiatwain.ds in this folder at it fails to work with WebTwain app for web applications (No drivers found).
Also there is one another computer where folder has a lot of files and everything worked fine.
But after folder was cleared (now there is only wiatwain.ds) WebTwain doesn't see scanners.
Can anyone tell me about this problem more deeply and how to fix it? Because everything I found in interned mentioned that this folder must be just ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reinstall the scanner driver to refill the C:\Windows\twain_32 folder.

All TWAIN drivers are installed there. Once cleared, drivers are gone, and Dynamic Web TWAIN and other TWAIN apps won't be able to see any TWAIN devices.

Answer (score 0):

"C:\Windows\twain_32 folder" is a folder where your scanner drivers resides.
So, when you install a twain driver, it should be install its files into this folder.

When you start your scanner program to scan from some device,
It will internally call "Data Source Manager"(DSM).
This DSM is already in your windows PC.(You don't need to install it.)
This DSM will find all scanner drivers available in your "C:\Windows\twain_32 folder" by finding "Data Source"(.ds) file.It will find all folders and its sub-folders.
After finding all ds files, It will give list of all installed scanner driver to your Scanner Program which will show you the list of scanner driver installed in your Windows PC.